# javascript notification center

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Looking for some wisdom. The scenario is the following. 
In a chat system, I have an array of connected users. When a new visitor connects, I would like to notify the first user in the array, if no answer after 1 minute, move to notify the second user and so on. If none of the users answers the request, I would like to cycle back to the top of the array. If no answer after 10 minutes, terminate the notification loop. Thanks,

Here is some relevant code.

```
socket.on('new_visitor', function (newVisitorData) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        users[i][_id].emit('send_chat_request', newVisitorData, function(data){
          // the notification was sent 
      });
    });
});


socket.on('answered_request', function(data){
    //stop the notification loop 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a code like this (I can't test it, hope there's no errors and this is the logic you are looking for):

```
function checkActiveUser(i, newVisitorData) {   
    users[i][_id].emit('send_chat_request', newVisitorData, function(data){
        clearInterval(clr);
        clearTimeout(clr10);
        // the notification was sent 
    }); 
}

var countUser;
var clr;
var clr10;
socket.on('new_visitor', function (newVisitorData) {

    clearTimeout(clr10);

    countUser = 0;
    checkActiveUser(countUser, newVisitorData); // first check

    clr = setInterval(function(){
        countUser++;
        if (countUser==users.length) countUser=0;
        checkActiveUser(countUser, newVisitorData);
    }, 60000); // 1min

    clr10 = setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(clr);
        clearTimeout(clr10);
    }, 600000); // 10min
});


socket.on('answered_request', function(data){
    clearInterval(clr);
    clearTimeout(clr10);
    //stop the notification loop 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I tested this method and it worked so far. I will probably be adding some more functionality but it is a good starting point. However, I wonder what if hundreds of visitor are connected, what kind of load will this put on the server?

Comment: @Crisenusa At your last question I can't answer, because it depend from your server, your server side code, the bandwidth of your server etc. Javascript is a client side language, and 1 minute timer is not a problem, hundreds of request every minute can be heavy to handle but as I said it depends from other factors. If you think the main answer is correct, remember to mark it :)

Comment: Thanks again @Baro. This code is actually on the server as is a part of a node.js/express.js app. That is why I was wondering on the load for the server if many hundreds of visitors request the chat. My apologies on forgetting to mention that. I was wondering is there is pattern to solve this like some kind of queue system.